# Detecting the previous view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently intending to detect the previous view controller in the -viewDidLoad method, and my intended result would be something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    if (lastViewController==firstViewController)
    {
        //do something
    }
    else
    {
        //do something else
    }
```

I did previously read about utilizing the viewControllers property of UINavigarioController (and in this case I am using a UINavigationController). However, I don't fully understand how are they supposed to implement such a thing in a if statement.

Comment: Is the controller added to the navigation controller when the view is loaded? When are the 2 attributes you show set?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to say you're trying to determine which VC is behind your current VC in the navigationController viewControllers stack? If so, you could use:

```
if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers[self.navigationController.viewControllers.count - 2]
    isEqual:firstViewController]) {
  //...
```

Comment: Umm, just asking, how do I get the 'firstViewController'? I mean what should I exactly put there? My root view controller is called SSTTopicsViewController, so what should I do?